# Search on a dynamic page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, search

i have a php dynamic website with a simple mysql search form which means a single index page with get page variable.

now my problem is when i do the search my page variable got replace with the only search terms.

please see the below code example.

This is my dynamic php starting page with the search form.

```
index.php?v=counselling
```

And when i do the search i get this..

```
index.php?name=value
```

my initial page variable in my case **V** get replaced with the search terms.

here is my html from tag..

```
 <form action="index.php?v=counselling" method="get">
```

i have also tried `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` but so far no luck.

what mistake im doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="v" value="counselling" />
```

Send it as a hidden input value along with your search input.

Comment: the method you have mentioned is worked..but is it the relevant solution for this sort of problem?

Comment: Yes it's the logical solution since you're sending GET data by form. v=counselling is also GET data so it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

when you have query string and post data together . you can be use this code . 
HTML code:

```
<form action="index.php?v=counselling" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="post1" value="value" />
</form>
```

PHP code:

```
echo "use $_GET and $_POST together. ";
echo $_POST['post1']. ' ' .$_GET['v'];
```